# Constraints with Label on Image View

Tags: ios, user-interface, debugging, swift2, constraints

In my app I have a Image for my background with labels on top of it that are not moving correctly on the iPhone 6 Plus. I am having trouble with the constraints to make the labels move correctly with the image. With the screenshot I attached what constraints should each label have to keep it aligned with the image? Thank you!
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PdjR.png)

this shows the suggested constraints
[constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q11d.png)

Comment: could you post screen of your storyboard, where constraints are properly highlighted? Like this http://pasteboard.co/f00c03uaU.png

Comment: i added a screenshot of the suggested constraints that do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraints aim on left alignment. So that's way it only works on the size that you were building on, and other display sizes are not aligned properly.

Try to, at least these:

1. add left leading constraint between superview and textField
2. add right trailing constraint between button and superview
3. add spacing constraint between textfield and button
4. set exact width constraint of your button.
   ... then add suggested constraint or add your own to them.

Like this (iPhone 6):

[image]

View as iPhone 6 Plus:

[image]

View as iPad Portrait:

[image]

... etc

Is that exactly what you asked?